# Casting pointers for arithmetic - C

Tags: c, pointers

If I have a void * x, but I want to cast it to a char *, so that the ++ operator will make it point to the next byte and not the next 4 byte block.

However, when I do:

```
(char *) x -= byte_length;
```

The compiler complains:

```
Error, lvalue required as left value of assignment.
```

Where am I going wrong please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the ++ operator will treat a `void*` like an `int*`?

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

```
 x = (char*)x - byte_length;
```

Cast `x` to `char*`, then apply the offset, then assign back to `x`. Since `void*` is assignment compatible with all pointer types no further cast is needed.

Answer (score 5):

`(char *)x` evaluates to a temporary with the same value as `x` but a different type. The compiler won't allow `-=` on a temporary. Do

```
x = (char *)x - byte_length;
```

The situation is analogous to the following:

```
short x = 0;
(long)x += 1;     // invalid; (long)x is a temporary
x = (long)x + 1;  // works
```

Comment: In your second example the cast is not always useless, in some systems, `x = x + 1` can be UB where `x = (long) x  + 1` would not be. For example in 8-bit systems, where `short` and `int` are usually 16-bit and `long` 32-bit.

Comment: @ouah: Why would `x = (long)x + 1` be defined behaviour where `x = x + 1` isn't?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth in my example (`short` and `int` 16-bit) when `x` is `SHRT_MAX` we have `x + 1` that is UB because of the signed overflow while there is no overflow in `(long) x + 1`.

Comment: @ouah: Sure, but there's UB as soon as you try to assign it back to `x`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth in `x =  x + 1` the UB occurs in the evaluation of `x  + 1` and in `x = (long) x + 1` the assignment is not UB, it is ruled by the rules of the integer conversions in 6.3.1.3p3 (C99). Integer conversions between integers never overflow.

Comment: @ouah: Ok, the result is implementation-defined, not undefined (see 6.3.1.3).  But that's not a great deal better.

Comment: Removed the comment, although I feel the use case for `x = (long)x + 1` is rather exotic.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
void* x;
char* cx = (char*)x;
cx -= byte_length;
x = cx;
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this as a solution but I wasn't sure if there was still a one line solution

Comment: Agree, I was more in the mode of "I'm going to need this later as a `char*`". In that case, it's much better to use `cx` then to cast every time with `char*`. If this is the only operation you are doing on `x` as `char*`, then sure, casting on one line is best.

Answer (score 1):

```
(char*) x -= byte_length;
```

In this statement, `(char*) x` creates a *temporary value* with `char*` as type. You can only assign to variables, or more precisely, *references* (or an `lvalue` according to your compiler).

One way to get a *reference* to it is casting the *address of x* to `char*` and dereferencing that:

```
*(char*) &x -= byte_length;
```

Comment: @Alex I used to wonder what they meant, and usually use C++ (hence the *references*), but when I wrote this I realized C++ just allows you to use *references* as automatic pointer `lvalues` of some sort.

Comment: Aren't there also references, whose underlying objects can't be changed through them?

Comment: @Alex You mean `const` references. They act like `const` pointers. They are often used instead of pointers (for readability's sake) when passing around big objects.

Answer (score 0):

`(char*)x` is a temporary value that has not address in memory. You can't do a `--` to it, for the same reason that if you have `int i`, you can't do `(i+5)++`.

You should do `x=(char*)x-byte_length;` instead.

See also http://c-faq.com/ptrs/castincr.html